# Routing to a fixed URL in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Suppose I am working in a project called `sampleProject`. When a particular URL suppose `/example/action` is entered how will it redirect to another URL i.e. `www.facebook.com` ?

This is the code I'm trying:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "catalogAnnualreport2013", //Route Display Name
    "/catalog/annualreport2013",

    RedirectResult ("www.facebook.com")                    
);
```

Answer (score 7):

In the `global.asax` file, you can simply do this:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("YourReRoute", "example/action", "www.facebook.com");
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following error while trying this:VirtualPath must be a non-empty string starting with ~/.
Parameter name: virtualPath

Comment: @MrutyunjayaMohapatra: It's probably because you're not implementing it as-is in the answer. This is code that I took from my website so I know it works.

Comment: @TomRedfern I'm puzzled as to why you approved (and improved) the suggested edit on this answer. It was a *follow-up question* being edited in place of the answer here, not a suitable improvement of the post.

Comment: @MartijnPieters good spot - I guess my usual iron focus must have slipped. Apologies to frenchie - I will take greater care in the future.

Comment: @TomRedfern: no problem, and thanks for responding. :-) The OP of this answer [learned how to roll back](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274361/) today, in any case!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirect(v=vs.118).aspx) in your `Action` like that:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    return Redirect("http://www.facebook.com");
}
```

Comment: There's no need to create a controller just to reroute a URL.

Comment: I am using  routes.MapRoute("catalogAnnualreport2013", //Route Display Name
                "/catalog/annualreport2013", ... <here i want to redirect to www.fb.com" );..

Comment: @MrutyunjayaMohapatra: well then if you're already using MapRoutes (I assumed you were) you don't need the controller at all, just handle the problem in the global.asax and you're done.

Comment: @frenchie agree, not a reason for downvoting though. From question I understood that author already had a controller and action for that URL.

Comment: @Vladimirs: you're right, I removed the vote. In fact, upvoted for effort.

Comment: I have modified the question. Please suggest

Comment: @MrutyunjayaMohapatra Try to remove your route and follow frenchie's suggestion